# Liquibase preconditions: How do I check for a column being the correct data type?

Tags: java, spring-boot, teradata, liquibase, preconditions

I have a db upgrade script to change some datatypes on a few columns. I want to do a `preCondition` check, and call `ALTER TABLE` only when it is a DECIMAL datatype, but I will want it to be changed to INTEGER.

Couldn't find a predefined precondition for this, and could not write an `sqlCheck` either.

Comment: Why do you want to do a precondition check? In general, you shouldn't need to do that, because Liquibase will keep track of whether the alter table has been run or not.

Answer (score 8):

There's no built-in `precondition` for column's `dataType` in `liquibase`.
You may just check whether the column exists or not. If it's already of the datatype you need, no error will be thrown.

**OR**

You can use `sqlCheck` in your preconditions and it'll be something like this:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
    <not>
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="DECIMAL">
            SELECT DATA_TYPE
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'your_table_name'
            AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column_name'
        </sqlCheck>
    </not>
</preConditions>
```

Comment: It'a good idea to check a schema name `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_table_schema'`

Answer (score 1):

Another answer already mentions how to do a sqlcheck.  However, the actual SQL for Teradata would be something different.

In Teradata you would use a query similar to the following and expect the columnType='D' for decimal values

```
Select ColumnType 
From DBC.ColumnsV 
Where databasename='yourdatabasename' 
and tablename='yourtablename' 
and columnname='yourcolumnname';
```

You could also do something like this if you want a more human readable column type instead of a type code:

```
Select Type(tablename.columnname);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was for Teradata, but principle is the same.

I prefer SQL files, so in changelog I have (for **Oracle**), is:

```xml
<include file="roles.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
```

and then in `roles.sql`

there is

```sql
--changeset betlista:2022-01-04_2200-87-insert
--preconditions onFail:MARK_RAN
--precondition-sql-check expectedResult:0 select count(*) from ddh_audit.DDH_USER_ROLE where id = 87;
insert into ddh_audit.DDH_USER_ROLE(id, role_name, description)
values(87, 'CONTAINERS_READONLY', 'Can read Containers reference data');
```

the query added by David Cram would make the trick.

I do not know and I didn't try if condition could be on multiple lines, I know `--rollback` can.